# How to clear PBS job history

Tags: pbs

How can I clear all the PBS jobs that have been finished or are having status 'F'. I just want to see job that are in Queue or running currently. This will shorten the output of qstat command.

Comment: I found that qdel -x <jobid> can delete job history.

Comment: The jobs will probably go away from `qstat` output automatically after some delay. There should be a `pbs_server` configuration setting that determines the delay.

Comment: @AmitRuhela that didn't work for me :/

Answer (score 0):

With

```
$ qselect -x -s F
```

You can view the ID of all the jobs that have been finished.

With

```
$ qdel -x <job_id>
```

You can delete a job history.

Combine them together with `xargs`.

```
$ qselect -x -s F | xargs qdel -x
```

This will delete every job history.